# Parameters referenced from the same variable point to different locations

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, vector, casting

I'm trying to store HWND pointers in an int vector along with other data, I'm using the following code to get the data and store it on creation:

```
void createscalingwindow(HWND &cswpara0,DWORD cswpara1,const CHAR* cswpara2,
                         const CHAR* cswpara3,DWORD cswpara4,int cswpara5,
                         int cswpara6,int cswpara7,int cswpara8,HWND cswpara9,
                         HMENU cswpara10,HINSTANCE cswpara11,LPVOID cswpara12)
{
    cswpara0 = CreateWindowEx (cswpara1, cswpara2, cswpara3, cswpara4, cswpara5,
                               cswpara6,cswpara7,cswpara8,cswpara9,cswpara10,
                               cswpara11,cswpara12);                     
    sizevalues.push_back((int)&cswpara0);
    snprintf (buffer, 20,"%d", sizevalues[zero]);
    MessageBox (NULL, buffer, "pointer", NULL);
    sizevalues.push_back(cswpara5);
    sizevalues.push_back(cswpara6);
    sizevalues.push_back(cswpara7);
    sizevalues.push_back(cswpara8);
    return;
}
```

This following code is a prototype that currently only shows the values in a messagebox, but I later plan to have it resize child windows to scale with the parent

```
void scalewindowsize (HWND &ownerwin, HWND &childwin)
{
    /*check owner window*/
    char buffer[100];
    int checknumber = 0; 
    while (checknumber < sizevalues.size())
    {
        if (sizevalues[checknumber] == (int)&ownerwin)
        {
            snprintf (buffer, 100,"%d", sizevalues[checknumber]);
            MessageBox (NULL, buffer, "foundit", NULL);
            break;
        }
        snprintf (buffer, 20,"%d", (int)&ownerwin);
        checknumber = (checknumber + 5);
        MessageBox (NULL, buffer, "fail", NULL);
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem is that the first `Messagebox` in `createscalingwindow` produces a value of 4235304 while the second one produces an entirely different number (the number varies). Why is this?

UPDATE: Found out part of the cause, in order to reproduce this the HWND used as a parameter to `scalewindowsize` must be used in a window procedure with the same parameter HWND in that window procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store non-`int` values in an `int` vector. That's asking for trouble.

Instead create a class that has fields (with the proper types) for all your values, and create a vector that contains objects of that class.

Your numbers changing is however likely caused by you taking the address of a local variable and using it after the function declaring the variable returns. You should just push the value of the `HWND`, not the address where it's stored. Handles are plain numbers, so there's no need to pass them by reference, unless you plan to change them in the function (I don't see why you'd need to do that in `createscalingwindow` either - you could just return the value)

Comment: why? I'd figure if they have the same value they'd convert into the same int value, is that not how it works?

Comment: @user1934608: Not if they're outside the range of `int`.

Comment: so if I use `intptr_t` to ensure that it's large enough to hold it it should be fine?

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: If you find documentation that guarantees that all those different types are small enough to fit in an `intptr_t`, then, perhaps. But why don't you want to create a class to hold your values? You'd get descriptive names for them, and nice type checks too. I for one would hate having to remember that `myVector[n*5 + 3]` is "the 7th parameter to `CreateWindowEx`", for instance.

Comment: because I unfortunately haven't learned how to yet. I'm still in the process of learning the basics to an extent, I think I'm going to pick up that book by stroustrup (or however you spell his name) in the near future.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Yes, learning the fundamentals of C++ (such as classes) would be a good idea before even venturing into using big external libraries such as the WinAPI... (but hey, you spelled Stroustrup correctly, that's a start!)

Comment: Yeah, now try pronouncing it.