# Do parameter references have physical variables?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, parameters

Do parameter references have physical variables? For example in the following code:

```
void scalewindowsize (HWND &ownerwin, HWND &childwin)
{
  char buffer[100];
  snprintf (buffer, 100,"%d", (intptr_t)&ownerwin);
  MessageBox (NULL, buffer, "fail", NULL);
  return;
}
scalewindowsize(somewindow, irrelevantwindow);
return;
```

Would `snprintf`'s call to &ownerwin return an address to the variable somewindow? Or would it return the address to the variable ownerwin? If it would return the address of somewindow but it's true that referenced parameters still create their own variable how do I access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return both, because `somewindow` and `ownerwin` are the same. That's what references are (aliases, the same object with a different name), and that's what passing by reference does.

Of course, there's a subtlety here in case `HWND` doesn't have the same alignment as `int`, in which case the cast would return a different address, but the same address for both nevertheless (unlikely though).

Comment: that's what I thought too, but look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112528/parameters-referenced-from-the-same-variable-point-to-different-locations I use referenced variables &cswpara0 and &ownerwin and when calling the functions I use the variable lobbywin to call both functions but they return different addresses?! If you could please explain why this is that'd be very appreciated.

Comment: @user1934608 probably alignment. The advice in the answer given there is correct.`(int)&cswpara0` looks fishy as well.

Comment: alignment? please elaborate

Comment: @user1934608 too broad of a topic, search google for `c++ data type alignment` - but in this case, I think it's exactly what the answer says.

Comment: I actually didn't read his comment before his revision about why the number is changing, but the part I don't get currently is if &cswpara0 is an alias to whatever I pass to the parameter (lobbywin in that case) and lobbywin is declared as a global variable then how can that be considered using the address of a local variable? Or am I thinking of the wrong variable or missing the point entirely? Also what do you mean (int)&cswpara0 looks fishy?

Comment: @user1934608 the first part you basically got right - they are the same object - regardless of whether it's a global or not. The thing is an address doesn't have to fit in an `int`. For example, you could have the address `0xFFFFFFFF` which could theoretically be outside the range representible by an `int`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22123/discussion-between-user1934608-and-luchian-grigore)

Answer (score 0):

It would return the address to the variable `somewindow` (before the cast).

Answer (score 0):

A reference is just an alias for an existing object, it does not have its own storage. Taking the address of ownerwin returns the address of the HWND object that ownerwin refers to.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer address would be the same for `&ownerwin` and `&somewindow`.